# Why isn't spawn-protection protecting the spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, minecraft-mods, server-administration, minecraft-forge

I've run into a headache setting up a Minecraft server (using the FTB modpack). Having set up a sweet open air spawn-jail and moved the spawn point into it (using MCedit), I started hitting things as a non-op and noticed that the default spawn protection of 16 blocks radius worked fine for inside the house but wasn't enough to keep people from messing up the lawn, so I set it to 42 blocks in the `server.properties` file.

Now spawn-protection seems to be entirely disabled for non-op players, which I thought wasn't possible! Changing it back to `spawn-protection=16` doesn't restore spawn protection either. **Why isn't spawn-protection working on my server?**

---

Details and proactively answering likely questions:

- The spawn protection was absolutely working before I messed with the `server.properties` file.
- I have restarted the server every time I've changed the file.
- I have tried breaking blocks both with an account that was opped + Creative Mode before but deopped + Survival Mode to test, as well as with another account that was never opped or switched from Survival.
- The spawn point is legal according to MCedit.
- Running Feed The Beast BETA Modpack A v12 (which means Minecraft 1.4.2)
- The spawn jail looks like this (the spawn point is in the middle of the third floor, which is the top row of windows):

  [image: a picture of the floating spawn jail just to give context]
- My `server.properties` file:

  > ```
  > #Minecraft server properties
  > #Wed Dec 19 12:39:24 PST 2012
  > generator-settings=
  > allow-nether=true
  > level-name=FTB-Beta-A
  > enable-query=false
  > allow-flight=false
  > server-port=25565
  > level-type=DEFAULT
  > enable-rcon=false
  > level-seed=
  > server-ip=
  > max-build-height=256
  > spawn-npcs=true
  > white-list=false
  > spawn-animals=true
  > snooper-enabled=true
  > hardcore=false
  > texture-pack=
  > online-mode=true
  > pvp=false
  > difficulty=3
  > gamemode=0
  > max-players=25
  > spawn-monsters=true
  > generate-structures=true
  > view-distance=10
  > spawn-protection=16
  > motd=Minecraft With Friends
  > ```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Solved it!

A meandering discussion on the [Talk page for the server.properties article](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Talk:Server.properties#spawn-protection-size_vs_spawn-protection) on the Minecraft Wiki indicates that this is *Forge*'s fault. Apparently it redefines `spawn-protection` to be a boolean that turns protection on or off entirely (which you can't do in vanilla), and defines a new variable, `spawn-protection-size` for what the former variable means for a vanilla server.

As a side effect, it appears that a server with the Forge API installed will honour the default spawn-protection area of 16 blocks *until* you edit the variable, at which point it treats it as boolean and looks for `spawn-protection-size` instead, doesn't find it, and effectively turns spawn protection off entirely.

So this is what happened to me then. Adding `spawn-protection-size=42` to my `server.properties` file made spawn protection work (again) as expected. Redefining configuration variables is poor practice!

Comment: In addition, there has to be at least one OP otherwise protection is disabled.

Comment: @WesleyBaugh Was that true in MC 1.4.2 or FTB Beta A v12? I distinctly recall spawn protection working inside a 16-block radius *before* editing the config file, even when deopped (i.e., less than one OP).

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurred when Minecraft Forge started the 1.8.9 series. I personally didn't realize it until 1.11.2. I have since made a mod that resolves the issue and provides even more capability to what you can control happening at spawn. https://minecraft.curseforge.com/projects/no-op-spawn-protection