# Why can I place blocks but not water at my server's spawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-feed-the-beast, server-administration

I **can't** place water at my spawn. That makes sense. However I **can** break and place blocks. What gives?

If I op myself I can then place water. If I de-op myself I cannot.

However regardless of my op-status, I can break and place blocks.

Why is spawn protection working for some actions but not for others?

Note: Not sure if this matters, but in the areas I can't place water, if I attempt to place it, my bucket empties, but no water appears. However, if I click the bucket where I 'didn't place' the water, the bucket fills with water.

I'm using TechWorld

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96612/why-isnt-spawn-protection-protecting-the-spawn

Comment: That question does not apply to me, I've never changed the spawn settings. It also doesnt apply because some of my spawn protection is working (cant place liquids) but some isn't (can break blocks)

Comment: Have you tried disabling spawn protection completely?

Comment: @jeffreylin_ what would that accomplish? I'm not trying to place water there, I'm trying to figure out why it's not working properly

Comment: @ender it would work properly if you turn it off, but some would consider this a hack and not a fix.

Comment: which pack of Feed The Beast are you using?

Comment: @jeffreylin_ care to elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like a [bug](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-666) with 1.4.x with the spawn protection. The workaround is to define anything in your ops.txt and spawn protection should work properly.

The other option is to use a protection plugin instead of the vanilla protection.

Comment: Your name, a random string, anything works apparently.

Comment: @Ender If I understand correctly, it's just a list the server matches incoming users against. So if you don't want to be a permanent op, put something that will not match against any username that connects to your server.